# Can one package name be used for apps targeting different versions of Android?

Tags: android, version, package

I want to publish an application that contains some version-specific code, necessitating separate APKs for different target versions of Android.  For example, in 2.3.3 I won't want to deal with the ActionBar, in 2.3.3 and 3.x I will be calling `recycle()` on my `Bitmap` objects but on 4.x I won't, and so on.

The applications will all be identical apart from these restrictions, and there will be no overlap in targets (so the 2.3.3 version will ONLY run on 2.3.3, the 3.x version will ONLY run on 3.x and so on—it won't be possible to put a 2.3.3 version on a 3.x device).

Do I still need to have unique package names for each of these applications, or is there a way to tell Google they are actually the same application, but targeted at different Android versions?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Answer (score 2):

Android supports multiple APK for an application. So no, you don't have to make separate package names.